# Where to find defined language functions in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, function

I am desperate here, I need to change function that calls for translations __()
This should be alias for function trans() but I was unable to locate it in my working directory even with scaning all files for "function trans(".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are defined in the [`Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php).

As you can see in the source code, the [`trans()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/92d0de2d59bddb3251e281b1e9c767a123750139/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L849) helper is defined as follows:

```
if (! function_exists('trans')) {
    /**
     * Translate the given message.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $key
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator|string|array|null
     */
    function trans($key = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return app('translator');
        }

        return app('translator')->get($key, $replace, $locale);
    }
}
```

Also, as you said, the [`__()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/92d0de2d59bddb3251e281b1e9c767a123750139/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L884) helper is an alias for the `trans()` helper:

```
if (! function_exists('__')) {
    /**
     * Translate the given message.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $key
     * @param  array  $replace
     * @param  string|null  $locale
     * @return string|array|null
     */
    function __($key = null, $replace = [], $locale = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $key;
        }

        return trans($key, $replace, $locale);
    }
}
```